# Is there a performance lose (or memory leak) by storing widgets in an Application?

Tags: android, performance, android-context, slidingdrawer

I have a SlidingDrawer that is referenced in all of my activities. The drawer is quite detailed and has a deep hierarchy of views. Currently I have all of my activities calling the application context upon creation to receive the singleton copy of the drawer. When an activities onPause is called, it removes the drawer from its top level ViewGroup. This works, but I don't know if it is the best way of doing it.

Also an issue I'm having is context usage. The SlidingDrawer has some buttons that fire off some dialogs. Knowing that I can't pass the application context, I just created a `OnActivityChangeBroadcaster` and `Listener` which changed the references context for the drawer. But even with this the dialog always appears in the launcher activity.

Does anyone have any thoughts or wisdom on the matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This works, but I don't know if it is the best way of doing it.

You are leaking memory. Never pass widgets between activities. Never put widgets, or anything else with a reference to an activity, in an `Application` object or static data member, unless you are going to `null` out that reference when the activity is destroyed.

> Does anyone have any thoughts or wisdom on the matter?

Recreate your drawer in each activity, please.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to decouple the UI from the data. If many of your Activities use the same SlidingDrawer, I would separate the data that the SlidingDrawer is displaying into its own [non-UI] class so that it exists in only one place, and have each SlidingDrawer instance populate itself from that data. You can define your SlidingDrawer in XML once and `<include>` it in the all the layouts you need.

Then I would have one function that populated the SlidingDrawer with the data from your separate class (accessible via a singleton object or by making the data `static`). To achieve that you can either make a `static` method that takes the SlidingDrawer to populate as a parameter (`public static void loadSlidingDrawer(SlidingDrawer destinationView) {...}`), or you can extend SlidingDrawer and make that a class method accessible by each instance.

CommonsWare is correct, you'll be leaking memory all over the place with your current strategy. UI elements need to have the flexibility to be destroyed and recreated constantly, so it's a really good habit to get into to separate all your data into non-UI classes that you UI simply accesses to display. This decouples everything nicely and allows the framework to function efficiently.